# Scanf reads wrong integer when 0 in front

Tags: c++, codeblocks, scanf

This is my first question, so forgive me if I get something wrong. 
I am very new to programming, and I came across a problem I can't find a solution to online. When using `scanf` for an integer, if my imput starts with one or two zeros, in some cases it will read it in some other system (not even binary).
For example, `0020` will become `16`, `0030` will become `24`, `0100` will become `64`.

It seems to work with powers of `8`, and consider digits up to `8` (typing `0009` will cause it to print `0` and then `9`).

There might be a simple rule I'm not aware of, I'm sorry if the answer is obvious. Thanks in advance for anyone who answers!

Comment: you should post your code sample to help us understand

Comment: [This `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different notations for the popular bases (base 8, 10 and 16).

Base 8: Also known as Octal. You define a number as base 8 when you put a 0 in front of the input number. So when you input `020`, it is read as `16`in decimal.

Base 10: Also known as Decimal. You just write a number you want to input without any leading `0`s. So when you input `20`, it is read as `20`.

Base 16: Also known as Hexadecimal. You write it with an `0x` in the front. So inputting `0x20`, it will be stored as `32` in decimal.

If you are reading the number using `scanf()` with format specifier as <s>`%d`</s> `%i`, then it is reading an octal number and interpreting it as an integer.

Comment: The `%d` always means decimal (hence "d"), it will ignore leading zeroes and never convert to base 8.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `scanf` states that the format character `i`...

> `i`  Matches an optionally signed integer; the next pointer must be
>                 a pointer to int.  The integer is read in base 16 if it begins
>                 with 0x or 0X, in base 8 if it begins with 0, and in base 10
>                 otherwise.  Only characters that correspond to the base are
>                 used.

If you want to force-read a **decimal** integer then use format specifier `d`

> `d` Matches an optionally signed decimal integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to int.

So I imagine this is what you have:

```
int value;
int n = scanf( "%i", &value );
```

Change it to this:

```
int value;
int n = scanf( "%d", &value );
```